# Collision Free and Keyed-Hash Message Authentication Code

Tags: authentication, cryptography, hmac

- What is Collision Free? And how does it work?
- What is HMAC(Keyed-Hash Message Authentication Code)? And how does it work?
- How authentication can be achieved with HMAC?

Answer (score 1):

Collision free is the desired effect of computational methods behind hashing algorithms. When a hashing algorithm is collision free it means that for each input to the hashing algorithm the resulting hash is unique and cannot be duplicated with a different input.

An HMAC is the result of a algorithm typically described as a key derivation function or technique of key stretching. NIST currently recommends the PBKDF2 algorithm to generate an HMAC.

An HMAC can be used to derive a strong irreversible hash based on a user's input, such as a password.

For details on proper implementation of an HMAC for authentication please refer to [NIST SP 800-132](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-132/final)